# How do I add filename to my variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\workspace\TestPowershell\ -Recurse -Filter "app.config" | ForEach-Object { 
   $AppConfigPath = $_.Directory
}
```

Now I want two variables with

```
$AppConfigPath +"App.config"
$AppConfigPath +"App.11111.config
```

How do I get that to variables?

I have tried diffrent approaches but cant get it to rock.

```
rename-item –path $_.Directory –Newname ( $_.basename + "App.config)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the output to look like? Based on your question, I'm not really sure of what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: `rename-item –path $_.Directory –Newname ( $_.basename + "App.config)`  --> `rename-item –path $AppConfigPath.FullName –Newname ( $_.basename + "App.config)`.

Also, you said you want two variables. Do you want two variables or two paths coz `$AppConfigPath` is of type `System.IO.FileSystemInfo`

Comment: Have a look at the `Join-Path` CmdLet

Comment: I want two variables/path that looks like   $AppConfigPath + App.config and $AppConfigPath +App.11111.config. This will be 2 diffent path that I will use.

Comment: Then why use `Rename-Item`?
As @gvee has suggested, you are looking for [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6) cmdlet!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but if you want two additional variable, go ahead and assign the expessions you need to two new variables.

The path to the parent directory can be found in the `FullName` property, and you can use `Join-Path` to combine a directory path with a file name, like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\workspace\TestPowershell\ -Recurse -Filter "app.config" | ForEach-Object { 
   $AppConfigPath  = $_.Directory
   $FirstFilePath  = Join-Path $AppConfigPath.FullName 'App.config'
   $SecondFilePath = Join-Path $AppConfigPath.FullName 'App.11111.config'
}
```